# How to populate a table with values from the previous known occurrence entry in a given month?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table as shown in below snippet with following data. Each row has two keys "IDENTIFIER" , "NEW IDENTIFIER" combination for an entry month with other fields populated appropriately. For each a1 (IDENTIFIER) there could be multiple s1,s2 ( NEW IDENTIFIER ) for a given month.

**Expected transform table**

For each combination of (a1,s1),(a1,s2),(a2,s4) there should be a corresponding entry in the new table for all the missing months in the year 2020 starting from the first occurence date i.e if a combination starts in march - then the output should have entries from march to december.

Except that while generating new combination entry fields "FIRST NAME" , "LAST NAME" should be inferred / copied from the last know entry in the original table based on entry month.

Below in example / picture you can find that for combination of (a1,s1) => new entries for april , may have same values from march entry and july entry is populated from previous known entry month in original table i.e june and similarly september , october , november ,december are populated from august.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross join creates all the combinations to be filled, a correlated subquery finds what to fill them with:

```sql
create or replace temp table sparse
as
select '1' id1, 'a' id2, 'james' name1, 'wood' name2, '2002-01-01'::date month
union all select 1,'a','joyce','flowers', '2002-06-01'
union all select 1,'a','pat','strings', '2002-08-01'
;

with months as (
    select date_from_parts(2002, seq8()+1, 1) month
    from table(generator(rowcount => 12))
), months_ids as (
    select *
    from months
    cross join (select distinct id1, id2 from sparse)
)

select *
  , (select array_agg(name1) within group (order by month desc) from sparse where a.month>=month and a.id1=id1 and a.id2=id2)[0]::string name1
  , (select array_agg(name2) within group (order by month desc) from sparse where a.month>=month and a.id1=id1 and a.id2=id2)[0]::string name2
from months_ids a
order by month
```

starts with:
[image]

ends with:
[image]